# How to grant AWS API Gateway permission to read mTLS truststore URI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, mtls

I am trying to activate mTLS via custom domain on API Gateway with HTTP integration (using AWS console).  I have Certificate Authority truststore configured on S3, but cannot figure out how to grant the API Gateway read access to the s3: URI.  I have created an IAM role, but how do I attach to the API Gateway?  Options to assume an execution role seem available only for AWS Service integrations that need a role.  This is just an HTTP integration, but I need the permissions to activate the mTLS.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the necessary read permissions are granted automatically, and my problem was not directly related to mTLS.  When in doubt use: `curl -v --key private.pem --cert client.pem url`